# Is it always irreps of the symmetry groups that act on the wavefunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations

When a symmetry acts on wavefunctions, is it true that an irrep or several irreps act on the wavefunction?

Comment: Your language is sloppy. Operators act on wavefunctions, not symmetries, neither irreps. Operators are used in order to map abstract symmetries into the QM mathematical structure. So if A is an abstract algebraic structure whose elements we call "symmetry operations", then a (reducible/irreducible) representation of A is a continuous mapping into the set of bounded/unbounded operators on the Hilbert space which preserves the internal structure of A.

Comment: @DanielC And these operators then, are they always irreps or a sum of many irreps? Or could they technically look like whatever, that is, be some really ugly represenatation of the group?

Comment: Well, it all depends on what exactly the symmetry (group) is, i.e. what symmetries you want to implement/describe. The role of irreducible representations is not absolute, think of the Dirac spinor which is an element of a 4-dim vector space which carries a reducible representation of the (universal covering group of the) restricted Lorentz group, but an irreducible representation of the (universal covering group of the) full Lorentz group

Comment: @Mongelo In general an operator can be decomposed into a sum of tensor operators.  Whether or not these tensors transform irreducibly depends on the symmetry group.  They could, for instance, be indecomposable (rather than irreducible) under the group (if this group admits non-trivial indecomposables, as the Euclidean groups would).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the symmetry groups/algebras that appear in physics are semi-simple Lie groups/algebras.

By [Weyl's reducibility theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_theorem_on_complete_reducibility), every finite-dimensional representation of such algebras is completely reducible, i.e. a direct sum of irreducible representations.

By [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem), it is also guaranteed that all representations of finite group decompose into direct sums of irreducible representations.

Comment: The Poincare group would be a notable exception that is not semi-simple.

Answer (score 0):

A wavefunction (or any other relevant mathematical object for that matter) may reside in a representation - either reducible or irreducible - of the symmetry. (Alternatively, it might reside in some nonlinear realization - but I assume you didn't mean that.)

Recall that any representation is either reducible or irreducible, and that a reducible representation is a direct sum of irreducible representations.

Comment: The claim that "any representation is either reducible or irreducible" is correct, but reducibility (defined as having a non-trivial subrepresentation) only equals decomposability (being the direct sum of two non-trivial subrepresentations) with some hypotheses on the group being represented (i.e it being finite or semi-simple Lie). In general, there are reducible but indecomposable representations.